# ssh host 'history | tail' produces no output

Tags: bash, ssh

Can anyone explain the following? When I use ssh to execute history remotely, no output is produced, even other remote commands do produce output and there is history on that machine.

```
ssh host 'history | tail' # produces no output
ssh host 'echo foo | tail' # produces 'foo' as output
ssh host
> history | tail # produces expected output
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

History is not loaded for a non-interactive shell. You can either `tail` the history file (`~/.bash_history`) or turn on history and load it.

```
set -o history
history -r
```

The full commands needed to do this from the remote host is as follows:

```
ssh host 'HISTFILE=~/.bash_history; history -r; history' | tail
```

Comment: Brilliant. Can you clarify what "history -r" does? Thanks.

Comment: @GirishRao: `help history` says that `history -r` reads the history file and appends the contents to the history list. That's why I said "load it" in my answer.

Comment: Strange: I noticed that `ssh -t localhost "HISTFILE=~/.bash_history; set -o history; export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '; history -r; history"` fails to give me the correct timestamp; it simply fills the current timestamp for all rows - any way to get the correct time?

Comment: @rupert160: If the history file doesn't have timestamps in it, the current time is output. In order for the correct timestamps to be written to the history file, `HISTTIMEFORMAT` needs to be set (it can be null) at the time the commands are added to the history.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson It does -it's just encoded in the #934335324 value above the command. for some reason this `history -r ` jiggery pokery seems to cause some problems with the logging daemon. I'll update when I understand what I'm doing wrong...